# Output List String Values Into Different Labels in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, list

Can you guys help me figuring out how I can store individual list string values into different labels.

For example:

MyListString has this values : "One","Two","Three","Four","Five"

And I have five labels at the same time : Label1,Label2,Label3,Label4,Label5

I wanted to store "One" into Label1, "Two" into Label2 and so on ..

Thank you in advance . :)

Comment: use a collection for that which stores key and value pair

Comment: can you make a sample? :)

Comment: try yourself a bit and show me where you are stuck... i will surely help you out

Comment: Hi . I actually tried doing this kind of logic .

Dim MyListString As New List(Of String)

Label1.Text = MyListString.Item(0)
Label2.Text = MyListString.Item(1)

And this one worked . Is there any smarter way doing it?

Answer (score 1):

You can also put your labels in a list. You would do this once on the initialization part of your program.

```
Dim myListLabel As New List(Of Label)

myListLabel.Add(Label1)
myListLabel.Add(Label2)
myListLabel.Add(Label3)
myListLabel.Add(Label4)
myListLabel.Add(Label5)
```

Then you just need to loop.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To myListString.Count-1
    myListLabel(i).Text = myListString(i)
Next
```